# How to use reflection to link a const string field from one class to a readonly object field in another class

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I have a class containing string constants and a class containing readonly objects representing a counter object. I have created a custom attribute that tags the string constant with the string representation of it's corresponding counter. Is there a good way to link the string const to the counter object using the attribute?

Here is an example of the string const:

```
public static class OperatorDiagnosticsConstants
{
  [CounterType(CounterType = "ReagentProbe1")]
  public const string R1_PROBE_CODE = "SACT-158";
}
```

Here is the class containing the readonly counter objects:

```
public class MaintenanceCounterType : CounterTypeEnum
{
    public static readonly MaintenanceCounterType ReagentProbe1 = new MaintenanceCounterType(MaintenanceCounterTypeConstants.ReagentProbe1ID);
}
```

I can think of two solutions but wonder if there is a more elegant way?
First is in the code that uses these two classes, I could have a convert method with a switch statement. Switch on the attribute string to return the `MaintenanceCounterType`

```
public MaintenanceCounterType Convert(string attributeStr)
{
   switch (attributeStr)
   {
      case "ReagentProbe1":
        return MaintenanceCounterType.ReagentProbe1;
      ......
   }
  }
```

Or I think I could add the same custom attribute `CounterType` to the `MaintenanceCounterType` and use reflection to match them up. I guess by checking the equality of the string property of the custom attribute?

Looking for a more elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do.  Are you possibly trying to achieve something similar to the Registry Pattern?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "link"?

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson - I guess I'm trying to solve the issue of maintainability. The two implementations I noted will both work but require a decent amount of overhead whenever adding a new counter. I'm trying to figure out a better way then a huge switch statement to get from having a string of "R1_PROBE_CODE" to MaintenanceCounterType.ReagentProbe1.

Comment: @stephen.vakil - I'm not familiar with that pattern so I'll go check it out. Thanks for the suggestion. All I'm really trying to do is find a better way to get from an "R1_PROBE_CODE" to the corresponding MaintenanceCounterType.ReagentProbe1. New "counters" keep being added and it seems like a lot of overhead to keep adding to switch statements. I'd rather just be able to loop over all the fields in each class and match them up. But I'm not sure of a clean way to do that.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - Link probably isn't the best word. I'm trying to match an OperatorDiagnosticsConstant string with  value "R1_PROBE_CODE" to it's corresponding MaintenanceCounterType.ReagentProbe1. And I want to do so in a way that the classes and their methods that use these two classes don't have to add new cases or else if statements when new static strings and/or readonly fields are added to either one.

Comment: How is the string constant involved in all this? I don't see any usage of the constant in the code you posted. Right now the `Convert` method only provides the object of the field in `MaintenanceCounterType` named coresponding to the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use that approach, you might consider using C# enums, which have functionality in the API for converting between enum constants and strings.

Converting an enum constant to a string ([API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
public class ConvertEnumToStringExample {
   enum Colors { Red, Green, Blue, Yellow };

   public static void Main() {

      Console.WriteLine("The 4th value of the Colors Enum is {0}", Enum.GetName(typeof(Colors), 3));
      Console.WriteLine("The 4th value of the Colors Enum is {0}", Enum.GetName(typeof(Colors), Colors.Yellow));
    }
}
```

Converting a string to an enum constant ([API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
public class ConvertStringToEnumExample {
   enum Colors { Red, Green, Blue, Yellow };

   public static void Main() {

      string colorString = "Yellow";
      Colors colorValue = (Colors) Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), colorString); 

      // colorValue is now Colors.Yellow

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An immediate drop in improvement would be to use the `nameof` operator, so that the link survives any refactoring/renaming:

```
[CounterType(CounterType = nameof(MaintenanceCounterType.ReagentProbe1)]
public const string R1_PROBE_CODE = "SACT-158";
```

The convert method can also be simplified using reflection, as you suggested:

```
public MaintenanceCounterType Convert(string attributeStr)
{
    return typeof (MaintenanceCounterType).GetField(attributeStr);
}
```

That being said, my preferred option in these situations is to replace the string constants with a new class:

```
public static class OperatorDiagnosticsConstant
{
    public readonly string Value;
    public readonly MaintenanceCounterType CounterType;

    private OperatorDiagnosticsConstant(string value, MaintenanceCounterType counterType)
    {
        Value = value;
        CounterType = counterType;
    }

    public static OperatorDiagnosticsConstant R1_PROBE_CODE = new OperatorDiagnosticsConstant("SACT-158", MaintenanceCounterType.ReagentProbe1);
}
```

If you want to attempt to maintain backwards compatibility with existing code that calls OperatorDiagnosticsConstants.R1_PROBE_CODE, you can add an implicit string cast operator:

```
public static class OperatorDiagnosticsConstant
{
    ...

    public override stirng ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(OperatorDiagnosticsConstant constant)
    {
        return constant.ToString();
    }
}
```